# Migrating Data to Another Database whit FDOToolbox

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, database, migration

I want to migrate my data (Shapefile) to a PostgresSQL using a FDOtoolbox , i searched a tutorial for that but i dont found it . 
can any one explain the steps to do for migarte the data from a database to another one.

Comment: Do you want to migrate from files to database or database to database?

Comment: From database to database.

Comment: Can you not do a backup and restore?

Comment: no the shapefile's backup is incompatible with a PostgresSQL , you should use a database migration tools.

Comment: From your comment, you are migrating from database to database.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you have to a FDOtoolbox solution or if that is just your preference, because another good option for this sort of work is [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). Once it is installed you can just run something like this from the command line.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=myuser dbname=mydb password=mypass" my_file.shp
```

Comment: I dont have just a shapefile i have multiple  files and databases,  files in arcgis (shapefile) and database on acces.  Not jist a spatial files or databases